# Java, using input from JOptionPane for a double variable?

Tags: java, input, double, joptionpane

Thanks in advance for any help. So I've used input from JOptionPane many times before but this is confusing me. I only want to use the input from the paymentField which takes in ($0.00) a value from the user. Do I use an action listener for this and if so how or is there another way?

At the minute Im using showInputDialog but it brings up an extra unwanted text field. Also tried showConfirmDialog but couldnt seem to use what was entered.

```
//method used to display dialog box required add funds to wallet
    public void getWalletBox() {
    String[] cTypes = {"Maestro", "Visa Debit", "Mastercard", "American Express"};
    JComboBox cardType = new JComboBox(cTypes);
    cardType.setFont(new Font("Serifs", Font.BOLD, 16));

    JTextField cardNumField = new JTextField(20); //width of text fields = 25
    cardNumField.setFont(new Font("Serifs", Font.BOLD, 16));

    //formats payment field using dollar prefix
    NumberFormat paymentFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
    paymentField = new JFormattedTextField(paymentFormat);
    paymentField.setValue(new Double(0.00));
    paymentField.setFont(new Font("Serifs", Font.BOLD, 25));
    paymentField.setEditable(true);
    paymentField.setForeground(Color.green);

    //array of objects used to add labels and fields to joptionpane
    Object[] fields = {
            "Card Type: ", cardType,
            "Card Number: ", cardNumField, 
            "Add: ", paymentField
    };
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, fields, "Wallet", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
}`
```

Comment: Take a look at Type-casting and Exceptions (try/catch blocks). It will help you with what you want to do.  Also, take a look at the documentation for showInputDialog, you can get the value entered.

Answer (score -1):

You have to define your own JDialog for that as that is much simple as compared to cutomize it using this method.